# Translate ID into a displayname

Tags: fieldtype

I'm trying to index the Sitecore item fields. Each field has a type and I saw that some field types contain an item ID(or Media item) and other the display name. For example(data from the REST API)

```
"Grouped droplink": "{66BDC8CD-5311-4CBD-BCAE-76BDAFASD42C}"

"Grouped droplist": "Test Item"
```

The values for a `Grouped droplink` field are IDs, and the values for `Grouped droplist` field are display names.

**Question:** Is there a way to received the values from those fields in the same way, all items or all display names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index always stores the raw values of a field. In your case Grouped droplink raw value will be ID of the referred item.

If you need to have the Display name or any other value referred item, you will have to use the computed index fields.

You can refer the below link for computed index fields 
https://www.3chillies.co.uk/blog/2015/10/code-how-to-create-a-computed-index-field-in-sitecore-8-solr-lucene

Comment: thanks, the response make sense but I am not using solr. I am posting another question  as a followup: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13822/receive-display-names-when-retrieving-sitecore-items-using-the-rest-api

Comment: Hi Diego, this doesnt needs to be solr. can be done in any search you use in sitecore. I will have at the other question as well.